# Appcelerator Live View Console.Log not working

Tags: ios10, appcelerator-titanium, console.log

Odd one this. Ever since upgrading to iOS10 and the latest Appcelerator SDK (5.5.0), I can't get even a simple `console.log("hi!")` to show anything in the console when I'm testing on an iPhone 6s Plus connected to my Mac via USB, using LiveView.

I've tried changing it to `Ti.API.info("hi!")` - which I believe is the old way to do it - to no avail. If I change it to `alert("hi!")`, that works fine. However, it's not as useful as `console.log` used to be when developing things which MUST be tested on a connected device (the camera, in my case).

I've Googled this, plus done extensive searching on StackOverflow.

It may be that this is so new that no-one has noticed yet.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue. Apple changed something with the way they log data. The Appcelerator SDK has to be adapted to this changes. I'm pretty sure they'll fix it asap. You'll have to await an update.

Greetings

Edit: Here is the corresponding jira ticket (https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23786)

Comment: Thanks for this! The last place I would have thought of checking was their JIRA. Lesson learned.

Comment: Geees why are we not better noticed on such breaking changes/issues like this...almost break my laptop in two... As above, lesson learned