# Ti.API.info() not writing to console

Tags: ios, console, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am running the following:

- 6.0.1.GA,
- iOS 10.2 Simulator,
- xCode 8.2.1,
- MacOs 10.12.3,
- node 4.6.2,
- Java 8 Update 121 (build 1.8_121-b13),
- Appcelerator IDE 4.8.1.

When I create a 'classic' project, go into the `app.js` file and put in `Ti.API.info('some text');` this is not shown in the console.

I have Trace enabled.

Can someone please help? it has been 4 days without this working. I have reinstalled xCode and Appcelerator including its CLI.

To note: If I run xCode 7.3 with Titanium 5.5 GA, then I can see the console log entries from the Ti.API.info() call.

**Edit:**
The Terminal in Mac OS and the console within Appcelerator after building the App shows up with the message: `Trying to connect to log server port 19920...`
However it does not come  back with another message (as it should) to say it has successfully connected.

There should be no conflict with the port number as Appcelerator intelligently uses another port if that port is used - Read it has 50,000 ports to choose from.

Also tried to use the `<log-server-port></log-server-port>` ios setting in tiapp.xml to force a port number, did not work.

Comment: are you sure it is hitting the line? Does an alert instead work?

Comment: absolutly, I did the same at home with a somiulair setup and it showed up with the comments with both console.log and Ti.API.info

Comment: similar setup doesn't mean the same. Test on the exact setup to see if the `alert` is called

Comment: Alerts come up on both

Answer (score 0):

There are some developers that also have this issue, I think it only affects iOS.

Have you tried with **console.log** instead of **Ti.API.info**?

If you are trying to get database exception logs, on iOS you'll only get if you're using a SDK prior to 6.0.0

Comment: I have tried both console.log and Ti.API.info, neither work for me on this machine but strangely despite being the same setup, it works on our other Mac.
I am writing it out using a classic project and just pure text, nothing else.

Comment: can you try it in the Terminal?

Comment: I ran it in the terminal with no luck

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're experiencing the same issue I got after updating appcelerator to 5.5 (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39654464/6868718). You could try an additional software like "iOS Console" to get the log.

Although the error should've been fixed in 5.5.1, I still seem to be unable to have appc log iOS correctly. Meanwhile android spams the log with unnecessary messages.